# Ehcache Refresh cache not periodically but conditional

Tags: spring, caching, refresh, conditional-statements, ehcache

I am using ehcache with spring architecture.

Right now, I am refreshing the cache at FIXED interval of every 15 minute from the database.

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "fpodcache",refreshInterval=60000, decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
public List<Account> getAccount(String key) {
     //Running a database query to fetch the data.
}
```

Instead of time based cache refresh, I want CONDITION BASED cache refresh. There are 2 reasons behind it -
1. database doesn't update very frequently(15 times a day but NOT at fixed interval) and 2. data fetched and cached is huge.

So, I decided to maintain two variables - a version in database (version_db) and one version in cache (version_cache). I wish to put a condition that if(version_db > version_cache) then only refresh cache, otherwise dont refresh. Something like -

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "fpodcache", conditionforrefresh = version_db>version_cache, decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
public List<Account> getAccount(String key) {
     //Running a database query to fetch the data.
}
```

What is the right syntax for conditionforrefresh = version_db>version_cache in the above code ?

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check in the beginning of your refresh logic to do the check you need.

If true then load from DB otherwise use the existing loaded data.

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "fpodcache",refreshInterval=60000, decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
public List<Account> getAccount(String key) {
 // Fetch version_db
 // Fetch version_cache
 // Check if version_db>version_cache
 // Is true --> Run a database query to fetch the data.
 // Else --> Return existing data
}
```